# Rebinding thumbpad mouse keys?

Tags: 14.04, mouse

Ive got a new mouse the utech venus, with a huge 12 button thumbpad. I want these rebound off the numbers, and onto more unused keys. I did xinput test, and found that the sensor, LMB RMB and midleclick aswell as scroll wheel are on xinput 9, whilst keys 1 - 12 are on xinput 10, doing

1 10

2 11

3 12

4 13

5 14

6 15

7 16

8 17

9 18

10 19

11 86

12 82

how would i change the number they output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**xinput set-button-map "Mouse name" numbers**

I have a Logitech G400 mouse and change the 2 and 8 button:

> xinput set-button-map "Logitech Gaming Mouse G400" 1 8 3 4 5 6 7 2 9
>   10

Comment: "device has no buttons"